# Adobe Flash not working

Tags: safari, google-chrome, adobe-flash

I have a user on a MacBook Pro with Yosemite that tried to install Flash.  She downloaded the installer and ran it.  It said it completed, but Flash is not working in Chrome or Safari.  I downloaded the uninstaller from Adobe and ran it to uninstall Flash.  It said it was successful.  I then redownloaded the Flash installer and ran it successfully.  Still, Flash is not working in either browser.

Ideas?

Comment: Could you expand on how Flash is 'not working in either browser'? Does it crash or show any error message?

Comment: Google Chrome has Flash built-in and doesn't use Flash Player.

Answer (score 1):

One place to check is `chrome://plugins/` in Google Chrome. Just type that into the address bar and hit ENTER. You should see a list of all the plugins that are available through Chrome. If you've downloaded and installed Flash, you should see two entries there. One for your own install and one for the version of Flash that comes bundled with Chrome. It will also tell you there if the plugin is disabled or enabled.

Also if you go into Settings in Chrome and search for "Flash" it will highlight the "Content Settings..." button under Privacy. Check Plug-Ins under there and see whether "Block all" has been chosen from the available "Run automatically|Click to play|Block all" options.

Another thing to check for are [ClickToPlugin or ClickToFlash](http://hoyois.github.io/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/) extensions that can be set to selectively block Flash plugins. You can find the installed Chrome extensions with "Extensions" from the Window menu and the installed Safari extensions with "Safari Extensions..." under the Safari application menu.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of Adobe Flash.

One is already a part of the Browsers, called Plugin

To check in Chrome type chrome://plugins/ in the address bar, and see if it is enabled.

The other one is the Stand alone version of Flash player that will show up in your System Preferences.

Comment: it is enabled, but no flash appsare  loading in the browser

Comment: do the test http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html